# Bootstrap grid not working properly in google chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

So I have this website that uses a bootstrap grid system and which works 100% perfectly on firefox but not properly on google chrome or safari.

How is this so?

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Index</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#INDEX" aria-controls="INDEX" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">INDEX</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#INDEX" aria-controls="INDEX" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">INDEX</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#INDEX" aria-controls="INDEX" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">INDEX</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#INDEX" aria-controls="INDEX" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">INDEX</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#INDEX" aria-controls="INDEX" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">INDEX</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#INDEX" aria-controls="INDEX" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">INDEX</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="index">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                        <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                                        <div class="well">
                                        Lorem ipsum
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                        <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                                        <div class="well">
                                        Lorem ipsum
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                        <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                                        <div class="well">
                                        Lorem ipsum
                                        </div>
                                    </div>                                  
                                </div>                      
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="INDEX">...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Firefox:
[image: Firefox bootstrap grid]

Google chrome and safari:
[image]

**UPDATE**

Edited the post with the complete HTML.

Comment: Do you have any custom CSS on this page?

Comment: Nope, thats all there is.

Comment: Well, there's something else going on on that page other than the markup you provided and Bootstrap's CSS. That is all that is included in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zy3h4m4k/) and everything seems to be working fine on Chrome for me.

Comment: I've now included the header part of the HTML code to the original post aswell. As you can see; no custom code is used. Your jsFiddle indeed works, but this code does not work in real life (or is it just fantasy?).

Comment: `but this code does not work in real life ` can you provide a link for the live page or website.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, I was on a holiday :). I've uploaded the page to my website: http://projectremus.com/chrome.html

Comment: Could you re-check it, please? Still have this problem. Cannot find a solution online.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bootstrap 3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#nav-justified), there's an error with justified navs "in which resizing your browser horizontally causes rendering errors in the justified nav that are cleared upon refreshing". Perhaps that produces a conflict between elements, make some changes to see if your problem goes into that direction.

Please keep us updated and/or confirm if you have already found a solution. Best regards!